# CALayer drops shadow to each sublayer, how to remove?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-animation

I've got a UIView container with a table view in it, whose cells contain images and buttons.

I want to add a shadow to the outter-most container but when I do, I found shadows are also added to all the images and buttons. How can I only add shadow to the layer itself without its sublayers?

code:

```
listContainer.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
listContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 0);
listContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = .8;
listContainer.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you paste code above and below these lines ?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the shadowPath property of your layer?

```
listContainer.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:listContainer.bounds.CGPath];
```

Comment: Solved the issue for me perfectly, much better that alternative I was consdering of creating a layer for the shadow. Worked on OS X too.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem once and the issue was that the layers background color was transparent.

So if you have a UIView, or CALayer, and you are trying to set shadows on it, make sure that there is a background color to prevent shadows from being applied to the sublayers.